# Game Of Life program in Java

Tags: java, game-of-life

I wrote a program for Conway's Game Of Life in Java. Are there any improvements I could make?

main class:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class GameOfLife {
    
    static Board board;
    static Window window;
    static Input input = new Input();
    static BufferStrategy bs;
    
    //board and window setup
    public static void start() {
        window = new Window("game", 800, 500);
        board = new Board(window.getCanvas().getWidth(), window.getCanvas().getHeight());
        board.setUp();
    }
    
    //renders the board
    public static void render() {
        bs = window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            window.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(2);
        }
        bs = window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
            
        window.getCanvas().setBackground(Color.black);
        window.requestFocusInWindow();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
        
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, window.getCanvas().getWidth(), window.getCanvas().getHeight());

        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        for (int i = 0; i < board.getBoard().length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.getBoard()[0].length; j++) {
                if (board.getState(i, j, board.getBoard())) {
                    g2d.fillRect(i * board.getCellSize(), j * board.getCellSize(), board.getCellSize(),
                            board.getCellSize());
                }
            }
        }

        g2d.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
    
    //timing for framerate
    public static void pause(long time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //main loop
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
        while(true) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            
            if(!input.getPaused()) {
                board.updateBoard();
            }
            render();
            
            long deltatime = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000;
            
            if((16 - deltatime) >= 0) {
                pause(16 - deltatime);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

board class:

```
package main;

import java.util.Random;

public class Board {

    private boolean[][] board;
    private boolean[][] newboard;
    int cellsize = 4;
    Random random = new Random();
    
    public Board(int width, int height) {
        board = new boolean[width/cellsize][height/cellsize];
        newboard = new boolean[width/cellsize][height/cellsize];
    }
    
    //getters and setters
    public boolean[][] getBoard() {
        return this.board;
    }
    
    public boolean getState(int x, int y, boolean[][] board) {
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x > board.length-1 || y > board[0].length-1) {
            return false;
        }
        return board[x][y];
    }
    
    public int getCellSize() {
        return this.cellsize;
    }
    
    //counts number of alive cells next to cell
    public int countNeighbours(int x, int y) {
        int count = 0;
        
        for(int i = x-1; i <= x+1; i++) {
            for(int j = y-1; j <= y+1; j++) {
                if(i != x || j != y) {
                    if (getState(i, j, board)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return count;
    }
    
    //returns state of cell in the next generation
    public boolean getNewState(int x, int y) {
        int count = countNeighbours(x, y);
        boolean state = getState(x, y, board);
        
        if(state && count > 1 && count < 4) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(!state && count == 3) {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    //changes states to those of the next generation
    public void updateBoard() {
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                newboard[i][j] = getNewState(i, j);
            }
        }
        
        for(int x = 0; x < newboard.length; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < newboard[x].length; y++) {
                board[x][y] = getState(x, y, newboard);
            }
        }
    }
    
    //assigns every cell a random state
    public void setUp() {
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = random.nextBoolean();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

window class:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Canvas canvas;
    static Input input = new Input();

    //window setup
    public Window(String title, int width, int height) {
        setSize(width, height);
        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(new Point(0, 0));
        setVisible(true);
        
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setSize(width, height);
        canvas.setFocusable(true);
        
        add(canvas);
        addKeyListener(input);
    }
    
    //getters and setters
    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }
            
    public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

}
```

input class:

```
package main;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Input implements KeyListener {
    
    private static boolean paused;

    public Input() {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            paused = !paused;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    
    //getters and setters
    public boolean getPaused() {
        return paused;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site! This looks good so far, here's a couple of smaller tips:

### Board.java

- The cellsize doesn't change, so why not make it a constant like this:
  `public static final int CELLSIZE = 4;`
  This also makes the getter obsolete, as you can access that field using `Board.CELLSIZE`
- `getNewState()` uses a boolean `state`. Renaming that to something like `isAlive` makes the if-clauses a bit easier to read.
- You only use the `Random` for the board setup, so there's no reason for it to be a (package-private) attribute of `Board`. Move it into `setUp()`.

### Input.java

- Boolean getters are almost always called `isX()` instead of `getX()`, so `getPaused()` should be renamed to `isPaused()`
- Make `isPaused()` a static method. This way, you can access the method using `Input.isPaused()` in `GameOfLife.java` without having to do `static Input input = new Input();` This also removes the unnecessary static member and the instance of `Input`.

### Window.java

- `setLocation` can also be called with two `int`s instead of a `Point`. This looks a bit more clean and saves the import
- Tip: you can center the window on the screen using `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`
- `setVisible(true)` is usually the last method called in the constructor. If you had a slower PC or a more complicated GUI, making the window visibile too early results in the user seeing the window build itself up and/or move around/resize.
- `input` doesn't need to be a static attribute of the `Window` class. Writing
  `addKeyListener(new Input());`
  works just as well.

### GameOfLife.java

- Move the `BufferStrategy`-related things into `start()`. I don't think that you need to call these every frame. I'd write something like this:

```
    public static void start() {
       ...
        board.setUp();
    
        if(window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy() == null) {
            window.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(2);
        }
        bs = window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    }
```

- `(16 - deltatime) >= 0` is a bit weird to read, `deltatime <= 16` is more intuitive. Also, if `deltatime == 16`, you'll sleep for 0 seconds; I'd put a `<` instead of a `<=` there.
- 16 is a magic number. Don't use these, instead consider doing something that's more descriptive:

```
private static final int FPS = 60
private static final int FRAMETIME_MS = 1000/FPS;
```

### General tip

Consider the visibility of your attributes. Make everything `private` that doesn't need to be seen or has a getter and setter. Also consider the scope: Does this variable need to be an attribute or do you only need it for one method? If so, move it in there.

Something about the Board/Window classes seems a bit off to me. I think that some things like the `window.getCanvas(). ...` could be cleaned up by making `Board` extend `Canvas` or making `Board` an attribute of `Window`, or even both. Perhaps I'll look at it again later.

Answer (score 1):

`Input` doesn't need to be a separate source file when you can use an anonymous inner class that implements `KeyListener`. When you do this, it becomes easier to put the variable `paused` where it belongs (i.e. not in the class handling the input). See my edits below for how to do it.

Similar thing with `Window` - it doesn't need to be a separate file, and we don't even need to keep a reference to the `JFrame` for the moment, though we might want to later.

You can move the cell size out of the `Board` class - the class with the game logic shouldn't be concerned with how it gets drawn. In fact, `Board` is actually the game logic itself, maybe that class should be renamed to `GameOfLife` and your main class renamed something else.

Though the code still does mostly the exact same stuff, I have made a bunch of other simplifying changes, so read through my version carefully if you are interested.

```java
package main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameOfLifeDemo {

    private static final long FRAME_TIME = 1000 / 24;

    GameOfLife game;
    boolean paused = false;

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    int cellSize;

    GameOfLifeDemo(String title, int width, int height, int cellSize) {
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.game = new GameOfLife(width / cellSize, height / cellSize);

        canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
        canvas.setSize(height, width);
        canvas.setFocusable(true);
        canvas.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                    paused = !paused;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(width, height);
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.add(canvas);
        window.setVisible(true);

        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        canvas.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private void render() {
        Graphics graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        graphics.setColor(Color.white);
        for (int i = 0; i < game.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < game.getHeight(); j++) {
                if (game.getState(i, j)) {
                    graphics.fillRect(i * cellSize, j * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                }
            }
        }
        graphics.dispose();
        bufferStrategy.show();
    }

    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            if (!paused) {
                game.tick();
                render();
            }
            long deltatime = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000;

            if ((FRAME_TIME - deltatime) > 0) {
                Thread.sleep(FRAME_TIME - deltatime);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new GameOfLifeDemo("Game o' life", 800, 600, 4).run();
    }

}
```

```java
package main;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameOfLife {

    private final static Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private final int height;
    private final int width;
    private boolean[][] board;
    private boolean[][] nextboard;

    public GameOfLife(int width, int height) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        board = new boolean[width][height];
        nextboard = new boolean[width][height];
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                board[i][j] = RANDOM.nextBoolean();
            }
        }
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public boolean getState(int x, int y) {
        return board[x][y];
    }

    private int countNeighbours(int x, int y) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
                if (i == x && j == y) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (i < 0 || i >= width || j < 0 || j >= height) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (board[i][j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private boolean nextCellState(int x, int y) {
        int neighbourCount = countNeighbours(x, y);
        if (board[x][y] && neighbourCount > 1 && neighbourCount < 4) {
            return true;
        } else if (!board[x][y] && neighbourCount == 3) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void tick() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                nextboard[i][j] = nextCellState(i, j);
            }
        }

        /*
         * Just swap the references to start using the newboard arrays as the current
         * board arrays. The old arrays will be used to construct the next iteration.
         */
        boolean[][] temp = board;
        board = nextboard;
        nextboard = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 especially for recommending to move the cell size out of the game logic.